# Conversion in SQL for secondary parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have the below sample table script:

```
create table #temp
(
    field_01 int,
    field_02 varchar(20)
)

insert into #temp
    select
        isnull(a.id,'UN'),
        a.textcol
    from 
        table1 a...
```

In the above table script, to insert value for `field_01` should be either `a.id`(which is an int) or `UN`. `Field_01` is integer and I'm confused about converting `UN`.

Getting conversion error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'UN' to data type int.

Should I convert the entire row or just `UN` part like `isnull(a.id,CONVERT(INT, 'UN'))`

Comment: You can't store a string (varchar value) in an integer column, either change your isnull to store -1 in case of null, or switch your temp table column data type to varchar for storing your id

Comment: why not just leave it null? What's the point of `UN`? That's what `NULL` is for.

Comment: My requirement says it should show 'UN' for null values

Comment: So do that in the presentation layer. Pulling it out of the database like that is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to select the data you need to convert the whole ISNULL statement

```
select
    convert(varchar,isnull(a.id,'UN')) as id,
    a.textcol
from table1 a...
```

BUT if you want to insert it, then you can't. You have to change the DDL of the table in order to insert a varchar in an INT column. You have to change the column from INT to VARCHAR, otherwise it is impossible.

***EDIT***: *To clarify as [scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) has said I'll add the complete query from the example given.*

```
create table #temp
(
    field_01 varchar(20),
    field_02 varchar(20)
)

insert into #temp
select
    id,
    a.textcol
from table1 a...


select
    isnull(field_01,'UN') as field_01,
    field_02
from #temp
```

Comment: your second statement is correct... but this makes your first one irrelevant based of their structure. I'd change your answer to simply state why they got the error, and how to fix it (ideally using NULL, not changing the datatype)

Comment: [@scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) your comment is helpful and right but if he is using the ISNULL function clearly his idea is to avoid null values. Anyway what you add to the discussion is valid!

Comment: This wasn't apparent until his last comment. I would still edit your question to show the insert without isnull, and then select from the temp with isnull

Comment: Thanks! This reply was helpful!